# Where did privileges go on the main site?

Tags: support

I was looking to see what my next level of privileges was, but could not find the [Privileges](https://apple.stackexchange.com/privileges) page linked from anywhere (I had to resort to a Google search)

Have I missed it, or is it truly missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you hover the mouse pointer over your name, a menu pops up; one of the items on that menu is a link to the Privileges page. Not exactly intuitive, but yes, it's still present. Note that this only works on the **Main** site, not the **Meta** site. If you try it right after you read this answer, it won't work!

You'll note that the URL for you is as follows:

https://apple.stackexchange.com/privileges/user/16529

You can plug in anyone's account number on the main site to see the privileges they are currently allowed due to reputation.

Comment: it's easily missed, personally I think it should be available within the site profile somewhere also.

Comment: I don't disagree. You could open up another meta post as a feature request.

Comment: I would suggest opening it up on [MSO](http://meta.stackoverflow.com), since it is very much a network-wide feature.

Comment: I found that MSO already has a few threads open on this; it used to be in the Reputation area, and was then removed.  There's another open thread where this has been requested to be but back (and agreed btw) but it has not yet actually happened.